# Passing information to JS File from Module File in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drupal-7

In one of my webpage I print one button multiple times and all have different logId. I want that when user click then there will JQuery into the picture and there should be no server side post-back. Since a unique log id is associated with every button so I pass the information to JS file from *.Module as below when the button is clicked:-

*.module File -- *PHP File*

```
$thm_button .= '<input type="button" class="clsPrevious" id="btnPrev_'.$user->uid.'_'.$logid;>';
```

*.js File

```
$('.clsPrevious', context).click(function (event) {
   var previousLog=this.id.split('_');

   //Retrieve log Id and Process the log id using AJAX call
}
```

This is working fine here but I feel there is security concern as everyone can view the log id of the button in HTML source.

Are there any ways in Drupal/PHP/HTML to pass the sensitive information to JS without showing in HTML Viewer.

Comment: Everything sent to your browser is readable - a user can create a web app to make the same http requests or use a browser debugger to see the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values from PHP to Javascript with "Drupal.settings".

Read more about it [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722).

You can create a input button which looks something like this.

`$thm_button .= '<input type="button" class="clsPrevious" data-myModule=" . $key . ">;`

where `$key` is a random/serial variable but is unique per Log ID.

Create a mapping array of key value pair and pass to javasript using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)()

```
<?php
  drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('_YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY_1_' => '_LOG_ID_1_')), 'setting');
?>
```

And now modify your click function to,

```
$('.clsPrevious', context).click(function (event) {

  var key = $(this).attr("data-myModule");

  // Now a this point you have the lookup table in Drupal.settings.myModule
  // use the "key" variable to find the LOG ID
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Please tell me if this is good idea to call multiple drupal_add_js in one PHP file.

Comment: yes, it is ok to call `drupal_add_js()` multiple times in the same function.